# Can't seem to feed data to D3 graphs when trying to implement them

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, 3d, scatter-plot

I am trying to implement these two graphs but I can't find any documentation on how to feed them the data I have. I have tried to read through the JavaScript files as well but I can't find where they receive the data that they are showing. Any ideas on how to go about doing this? Thanks!

http://bl.ocks.org/supereggbert/aff58196188816576af0

http://bl.ocks.org/hlvoorhees/5986172

Comment: voted to close because you didnt show code and asked a broad question, read the d3 docs, I think it's `d3.select('tag').data(myArray)`

Comment: @Plato well that escalated quickly, the code is in both links respectively. I thought it didn't make much sense to paste all the javascript code in here since I'm not even sure in which part they feed in the data. If you see the graphs they already contain data, so it clearly can be done without the `d3.select('tag').data(myArray)` Let me know if you can help out by looking at the code, it's not long at all

Comment: @Plato they don't use the d3.select command

Comment: In the example they feed the data using `ul.selectAll('li').data(surfaces).enter()`, where the surfaces array is generated earlier in the code.